# Can you add artifacts to a Jenkins pipeline build from within a script that it runs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a python script from a Jenkins pipeline job, and that python script runs another program that produces a log file whose name differs each run.

In the python script, I'd like to add that log file as an artifact of the jenkins build. Is that possible e.g. via the REST API?

There are other options like to have the jenkins pipeline pass extra arguments down to the python script specifying a random log file name, or have the python script return the log file name. However, it's slightly more complicated than I'm describing because the python script runs more than just one subprocess and I want to gather the log files for all of them. My best option is to have the python script move all the logs into a pre-determined (cleaned) folder and have the pipeline archive all files from there, but I think the REST API would be nicer.

Comment: Is the program that the python trigger run  on the same machine ?

Comment: Yeah the pipeline stage waits while the python script executes locally, and the python script waits while the subprocess it triggers runs locally.

Comment: So you asked a question and in the end also posted an answer, archiving log files with pipeline. You only need to know path and file extension or some other wildcard. Otherwise it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Essentially I'd like an arbitrary program to be able to check the environment variables to see it's running in a jenkins job, and upload a file that it deems to be useful as an artifact. Without the jenkins pipeline code needing to be aware of it, clear out a specific folder, and the program put the file in there.

Answer (score 0):

If all the programs runs on the same machine , you can copy the program logs into a clean folder in the workspace and archive the files.